# Fetch Data from InnerObject In ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am developing a app, where I am using nested Flatlist. In main-Flatlist we have renderItems, where in one of the item I have a inner-Flatlist in I am trying to show items in renderItems.
 I have json

```
    {
  "data": {

    "list": [
      {
        "name":"Developer",
        "detail_values": [
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          },
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"Developer1",
        "detail_values": [
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          },
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"Developer2"
      },
      {
        "name":"Developer3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From the above json, how can I fetch the "detail_values" array objects and display data in inner-Flatlist.

In inner-Flatlist's renderItem method, I have tried using .map and forEach. I get error stating Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
_renderItem({ item, index }) {
    const children = item.detail_values
    return (
      <View style={styles.cardListCell}>

        <View style={styles.view}>
          {
            item.detail_values.map(data => (
              <View><Text>{data.key1}</Text></View>
            ))
          }
          <Text style={styles.countValue}>
            {index}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Main Flatlist Code

```
return (
          <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={this.state.cardsMainModel.cards}// here cards is an array of models
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            horizontal={false}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractorInfoSection}
          />

        );
```

Inner FlatList Code

```
<View style={styles.innerView}>
    <FlatList
                data={this.state.dataSource} //datasource has `list` array
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
              />
   </View>
```

Comment: What are you passing in your `FlatList` as `data`?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya: The `"list"` array object to the `inner-Flatlist` as data

Comment: Just for debug purpose, print your `item` and check how you are getting data, you will get whole idea of issue.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya: Yeah I have done that,I am getting `{
        "name":"Developer",
        "detail_values": [
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          },
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          }
        ]
      },`, After that not able to proceed.

Comment: In that case only issue there might be is blank value or object in place of array. Check for `detail_values`, whether you are getting it in all the records?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya:yeah in 2nd & 3rd object `detail_values ` is not coming, it comes only in 0th & 1st object. 
But I have tried to fetch using `{item.detail_values[0].key1}`, it says `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: can you please add both flatlist code in your question?

Comment: @ParasKorat: I have updated the code could you check once.

Comment: @iOSDev where you set your list array to this.state.dataSource because when I run and set data it's working fine.so just mention that dataset.

Comment: @ParasKorat: I have set in `componentWillMount()`, where i am downloading data. and updating in completion block.

Comment: @ParasKorat: As of now as @RaviRupareliya mentioned for `detail_values` to be checked, I am checking that tag and doing the requirement. is that good to go ?

Comment: @iOSDev the JSON which you mentioned in your question is valid and I have tried to put it in flatlist its work fine but I thought because you downloading it so that's why this view going to give you an error because of initially null value or undefined state.I have try to put one condition try it may be it's going to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{item != undefined
 ? item.detail_values.map(data => (
 <View>
 <Text>{data.key1}</Text>
 </View>
 ))
 : null}
```

try this one.

Comment: Please use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining to check undefined variables it will be very helpful